# Turn on the android phone

Tags: android, alarm

I had old phone with one interesting functionality, that was ability to turn on on scheduled time. Actually the procedure was 1. Set alarm 2. Turn off phone 3. Wait for time to pass and the phone will go on without user interaction. I really loved this functionality cause you have active phone (it wakes you up) in the morning but no one can bother you during the night by calling you...

How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: How's an application supposed to run when the phone is turned off? Maybe it would be possible for an application to disable the screen, antennas, and (if it still has one) keyboard. But when the phone is fully turned off no application should be able to keep running.

Comment: Well in the older phone that I was used to do this it was possible. The phone was off but the alarm still was firing up, and also was turning the phone on.(btw it was Motorola C200) I guess that it is some native app that was running even the phone was off.I don't know if this is possible to be done on android phone , that why I am asking :)

Comment: Well my phone has got that functionality as well, but it's built in in the firmware. An extra application would not be able to do this, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't possible in Android. At least not exactly what you want.

You may set you phone to Airplane mode, or put sound and notifications in mute (this is what i do) for pre-set hours/days.

For this i use an application called Timeriffic ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic )

Answer (score 2):

I have BLU studio 5.3 dual sim android and yes, it can power off/on based on schedule...but it seems to me that it is the only android phone around the globe that can do this ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Thats an ideal scenario for the plane mode. In this mode it works like a simple device with no phone functions. You don't receive calls or sms and even wifi/3g is deactivated but the alarm will still wake you up.

Comment: Yes exactly this is something that works fine on Motorola C200 [far more stupid phone than any android phone :-)],but I guess they do not allowing app to keep on running when the phone is on(well I am almost sure) but the question is is there some possibility to do some scheduling ... well even on my TV there is option to turn on and off on scheduled time.

Comment: Turning off should be possible, but turning on is based on the ability of the firmware (the basic android os). Like RobinJ said...

Comment: You should be able to toggle airplane at set intervals.  Search SO for implementations of timer services.

Comment: The ability to turn the device on from a completely off state (as opposed to any kind of OS 'sleep' state) would have to be performed not even by the basic OS (because it won't be running!) but at a very, very low hardware level by an RTC clock that remains powered, but consumes little battery power (like the RTC with battery backup on a PC motherboard). It'd be up to the individual hardware manuafacturer to implement it. It's a shame that Android phones don't seem to offer such functionality, as it'd be nice to be able to turn the phone completely off sometimes but still have working alarms!